# Multiple definition of 'main' in C?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I got this error in my **CodeBlocks** Editor while working on the OpenGL project in **C**. This is my very first time using this, and **YES**, I've already seen questions with the same title as mine, but unfortunately, they couldn't help me. I tried making every line of code again, but it does the same. Could someone please help? Thanks.

Oh, yes, here is the code:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<GL/glu.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>

GLfloat Cx=0,Cy=0,Cz=3;

void MyInit()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-1,1,-1,1,2,10);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void Square(GLfloat A[],GLfloat B[],GLfloat C[],GLfloat D[])
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3fv(A);
        glVertex3fv(B);
        glVertex3fv(C);
        glVertex3fv(D);
    glEnd();
}

void Cube(GLfloat V0[],GLfloat V1[],GLfloat V2[],GLfloat V3[],GLfloat V4[],GLfloat V5[],GLfloat V6[],GLfloat V7[])
{
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    Square(V0,V1,V2,V3);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    Square(V4,V5,V6,V7);
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    Square(V0,V4,V7,V3);
    glColor3f(1,1,0);
    Square(V1,V5,V6,V2);
    glColor3f(1,0,1);
    Square(V3,V2,V6,V7);
    glColor3f(0,1,1);
    Square(V0,V1,V5,V4);
}

void Draw()
{
    GLfloat V[8][3] =   {
                            {-0.5, 0.5, 0.5},
                            { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5},
                            { 0.5,-0.5, 0.5},
                            {-0.5,-0.5, 0.5},
                            {-0.5, 0.5,-0.5},
                            { 0.5, 0.5,-0.5},
                            { 0.5,-0.5,-0.5},
                            {-0.5,-0.5,-0.5}
                        };
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(Cx,Cy,Cz,0,0,0,0,1,0);

    Cube(V[0],V[1],V[2],V[3],V[4],V[5],V[6],V[7]);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void Key(unsigned char ch,int x,int y)
{
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 'x' : Cx = Cx - 0.5;   break;
        case 'X' : Cx = Cx + 0.5;   break;

        case 'y' : Cy = Cy - 0.5;   break;
        case 'Y' : Cy = Cy + 0.5;   break;

        case 'z' : Cz = Cz - 0.5;   break;
        case 'Z' : Cz = Cz + 0.5;   break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argC,char *argV[])
{
    glutInit(&argC,argV);
    glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("Color Cube with Camera");
    MyInit();
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Key);
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

**Here is the full message as it shows in editor:**

`C:\Users\Saric\Desktop\C\OpenGL-Sample#1\sample.c|82|multiple definition of 'main'; obj\Debug\main.o:C:/Users/Saric/Desktop/C/OpenGL-Sample#1/main.cpp:140: first defined here`

Comment: What happens if you compile a Hello World program?

Comment: please show the exact error message, and which line it is on, etc.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It works perfectly fine, I've been using this for my C projects for a year and everything compiled good (obviously with errors, when I make mistakes xD), but after using OpenGL for the first time, I didn't know where do I make a mistake...

Comment: @OldProgrammer -Ok, here. Line 55; multiple definitions of 'main';

Comment: What happens when you don't include `windows.h`?

Comment: You've been programming for a year and still use a ludicrously obsolete compiler and IDE? That's kind of on you. Not to mention that you're using the obsolete OpenGL fixed pipeline, or that you're building seemingly Windows applications with `main` instead of `WinMain` as your entry point.

Comment: @RaLe Is there some additional message near `Line 55; multiple definitions of 'main';` that tells you the location of the other definition of `main`?

Comment: @Neil I had to include that, 'cause without it, it cannot compile

Comment: @Bodo I see what you mean. Here is the full: `Line 55; multiple definitions of 'main'; obj\Debug\main.o: ....Here goes the path to my project and its folder`

Comment: @Blindy It is how it is. When I first started I used GNU Nano 2.2.6 for C and C++, then I found out for CodeBlocks and installed it. That's it. That's me :D

Comment: and you don't have some `include "main.c"` somewhere?

Comment: OP may be linking with main.c and main.o as well.

Comment: I don't think you should need it. What error message does it give if you don't include windows?

Comment: @Neil It prompts the same one. I added more code. I'll update the question :)

Comment: @RaLe Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the error message there. I was hoping for a message like `path/to/some/file.c: 1234: previous definition of 'main'` or similar. Please also show the compile and link commands that get executed.

Comment: @Bodo I just updated it. :)

Comment: According to the error message I assume that the two named files `sample.c` and `main.cpp` contain a `main` function. One of the files should not contain a `main` function or shouldn't be used to build your program at all.

Comment: @Bodo TYSM! It worked! I'm so stupid! Anyways, thank you mister :)

Answer (score 1):

On my MSVC installation, `gl/glu.h` contains a `main` function:

```
int main(int argC,char *argV[])
{
    glutInit(&argC,argV);
    glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("Color Cube with Camera");
    MyInit();
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Key);
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

I a not used to OpenGL programming, but as this contains a main function that calls a `glutMainLoop` function, I would assume that you are not supposed to provide a main function, but only provide *handlers* for *events*.

Comment: Can you provide more info about it? Like can you show the full code of the file? Thanks.

Comment: @RaLe: I do not think that it would be a good idea. The full code of *my* file will contain implementation details for *my* version. Furthermore, I could not find `glut.h` on my system, so I do not really trust it. This answer is only an evidence that **at least some** OpenGL implementations contain a `main`. To go further, you should use **your** implementation and OpenGL documentation.

Comment: I understand You, fortunately I managed to fix my problem and you no longer need to share your files' source code :)